# Editing a CV after it is filed

Tags: support, jobs, cv

Is it possible to edit my CV after I have filed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can edit your CV any time. Filing doesn't do anything more than give you the option of having your resume appear in the Careers employer search.